# Is it possible to restrict accessed to jQuery mobile site by signing by unique phone number

Tags: mobile, mobile-website

i have jQuery mobile site,

Is it possible to restrict accessed to my site by signing by unique phone number ?

foe example, i have list with 5 phone numbers - Only these phones will be able to enter the site.

is it possible ?  if yes, how to do it ?

thanks

Comment: I don't think it's possible to access someone's phone number while they browse a site, let alone do it in JavaScript, so no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anyone can *enter* any phone-number; as data from the client it should not be trusted. Even if this information was available innately to JavaScript or the server - it is not, spammers/advertisers would love it it were! - it would be unwise to rely on it for "security" as phone numbers are not [usually] secrets.

However, one could use the 2nd factor ("has something") of a two-factor authentication: when a user says "hey, I have this phone number", send them an SMS with a nonce (one-time password). If the user enters that nonce, then they [currently] have the phone on-hand, or someone else has it..

..which is why 1st factor ("knows something") is still relevant.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot directly access clients phone number via javascript. But you can use other authentication methods which involve clients' phone numbers like SMS password sending through SMS gateway services.